# preg_replace adds < and > automatically, but it's weird?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I got this:

```
$_response_body = preg_replace("</body>","<script>alert('test');</script><br /></body>",$_response_body);
```

What it should write:

```
<script>alert('test');</script><br />
</body>
```

But it doesn't. It writes returns:

```
<<script>alert('test');</script><br /></body>>
```

As you can see, it adds an extra < and >.. If I remove the less-than sign and great-than sign so it says:

```
script>alert('test');</script
```

Then it will return:

```
<script>alert('test');</script<br /></body>>
```

Anybody got any idea why this happens?

Comment: use `str_replace()` instead

Answer (score 2):

In this case it'll be better use str_replace, instead preg_replace

```
str_replace("</body>","<script>alert('test');</script><br /></body>",$_response_body);
```

Comment: Thanks, you're the man. I never thought of str_replace ... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace` fails, because you forgot [delimeters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

```
preg_replace("#</body>#",
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `preg_replace`, which requires the first argument to be a PCRE pattern. These patterns are enclosed by [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). You haven't put any delimiters in, but it will treat the `<` and `>` as delimiters, so those aren't being considered part of your pattern to match.

Basically, it's not *adding* extra characters, it's just not matching as much as you think it is.

As gaskar points out, if you're not actually using any regular expressions, you might as well just use `str_replace`.